# Employer asked me to leave the job in 30 days

Tags: job-change, leave

My employer asked me to leave the job in 30 days, and added that I will not needed to be in the office for that period.

What should I do now? Go to the office or just stay at home?

Comment: You need to ask your employer, not the Internet.

Comment: Ask if you are you being fired, laid off, etc? If you don't show up for the rest of the 30 days, will you still get paid for them?

Comment: Round here that's known as "gardening leave"  You're technically still employed and paid, so you can start interviewing for a new job but you can't start working at a new job, unless you want to pay secondary-income tax.  Your country might be different.

Comment: If you're trying to edit this question yourself, please use the account which posted the question as then your edits won't need to be approved. If you've accidentally created two accounts, see [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to get them merged.

Comment: I assume your employer has actually given you notice officially. In the UK for example, if an employer was so amazingly stupid to say "please leave in 30 days and don't come to work in these 30 days" without actually giving you notice, you would be laughing.

Comment: If the boss said that you're "not needed at the office", I'd take that to mean that there's no need to come in. Whether you've been fired or laid off, they gave you 30 days notice. I'd neither go to the office nor stay open. I'd be out looking for another job.

Answer (score 12):

You got a months notice, congratulate yourself and begin job hunting and brushing up on your skillset.

I'm not about to believe you have no idea why, so I won't go down that track like the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

As Criggie said in the comments, it's likely gardening leave. It's not just tax that would stop you getting another job in that period, it would likely be a contractual issue too. The company is essentially paying you for the month to not go to their competitor.

Get the terms of your dismissal in writing, including the company's expectations diuring this period. Until then, business as usual. Go to work, look busy. If they send you home, get it in writing.

Now, what to do with your month off... Use the time for 3D: Decompression (get the old job out of your system), Development (improve your skillset) and Determination (get out there and line up a job for the first day after the 30 days ends).

Comment: Or it could eb the contract specify a 30 day notice mandatory, so he has to be paid 30 days even if he stayè at home.

Comment: Even if you can't start working somewhere else during those 30 days, there's nothing stopping you from applying and interviewing to minimise the time out of work after those 30 days have passed

Answer (score 1):

Seems fairly obvious, given the last bullet point above.

> •I have recently completed the project. So there is no work allocated for me.

If you've completed your project and there's no further work, there's no need for you to go back into the office again.

Time to move on.

EDIT: The clause quoted above seems to have been added by a third party, it wasn't there when the question was first asked.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would only go in each day if the alternative was being unpaid. If there is any loose ends you need to wrap up I would go in and do that as quickly as possible, then I move on and start my search for a new job.

You need to ask yourself is there any value to you going to the office over staying home and job hunting? When I was given a months notice by an employer we were given certain access to write up code for portfolios, retrieve anything personal from email etc.

I believe most of the people who were leaving used at least a few days for this purpose. However we weren't expected or allowed to work and were being paid for the month regardless so the majority of people only came in for a day or two.